# Java exception when creating multiple permissions on Google Drive documents

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-drive-api

In our application we need to share multiple files to multiple users with Google Drive api.

We use batching provided by the java client library of the Google Drive api.

This runs already in the production but we get a lot of unclear exceptions from the Google Drive api:

```
Internal Error. User message: "An internal error has occurred which prevented the sharing of these item(s): "
```

[image]

We handle the exceptions and retry with an exponential backoff, but these errors cause big delays in the flow and usability of this application.

What is the reason these exceptions occur? How to avoid those?

It would be very helpful if we knew what is going wrong when these exceptions occur, so we can avoid it.

Some extra information: 
Each batch contains 100 permission operations on different files.
Every minute a batch operation is called.

The code:

```
String fileId = "1sTWaJ_j7PkjzaBWtNc3IzovK5hQf21FbOw9yLeeLPNQ";
JsonBatchCallback<Permission> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Permission>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders)
        throws IOException {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Permission permission, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Permission ID: " + permission.getId());
    }
};

BatchRequest batch = driveService.batch();

for(String email : emails) {
    Permission userPermission = new Permission().setType("user").setRole("reader").setEmailAddress(email);
    driveService.permissions().create(fileId, userPermission).setSendNotificationEmail(false).setFields("id").queue(batch, callback);
}

batch.execute();
```

the variable emails contains 100 email strings.

Comment: Welcome to stack we can not help debug code we can not see and test please edit your question and add a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Question: exactly how many calls are you sending per batch?

Comment: Hi DalmTo, there are 100 calls per batch. I will edit my question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    {
    "code" : 500,
    "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error. User message: "An internal                                                     error has occurred which prevented the sharing of these item(s): fileame"",
   "reason" : "internalError"
    } ],
  "message" : "Internal Error. User message: "An internal error has occurred which prevented the sharing of these item(s): filename""
    }
```

Is basically flood protection. The normal recommendation is to [Implementing exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff)

> Exponential backoff is a standard error handling strategy for network
>   applications in which the client periodically retries a failed request
>   over an increasing amount of time. If a high volume of requests or
>   heavy network traffic causes the server to return errors, exponential
>   backoff may be a good strategy for handling those errors. Conversely,
>   it is not a relevant strategy for dealing with errors unrelated to
>   rate-limiting, network volume or response times, such as invalid
>   authorization credentials or file not found errors.
>
> Used properly, exponential backoff increases the efficiency of
>   bandwidth usage, reduces the number of requests required to get a
>   successful response, and maximizes the throughput of requests in
>   concurrent environments.

Now here is were you are going to say but I am batching I cant do that.   Yup batching falls under the same flood protection.  Your batch is flooding the server.   Yes I know it says you can send 100 requests and you probably can if the requests take enough time in between each request not to qualify as flooding but yours apparently doesn't.

My recommendation is you try cutting it down to say 10 request, and slowly stepping it up.   Your not saving yourself anything using batching the quota usage will be the same as if you didn't batch it.  You cant go any faster than the flood protection allows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try this out.

Comment: I went from 100 requests per batch, to 10 and then to 5. Each batch is processed every minute!!! And still I get the same error even after a long time there was no use of the Google Drive api. It seems to me if the error is about flood protection, than batching doesn't work at all...

Comment: Remember you are not the only one hitting the server you are on.  You are competing for recourses with other developers.   If you get a 500 error running your batch request then wait send it again that's what Implementing exponential backoff means.  Or just stop using batching I gave up on it four years ago TBH.

Comment: This is for v2 and its not batching but it looks like a similar issue https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4872

Comment: Hi, thanks. By not using batching it seems to work for my test case. I will implement that on the application too.

Comment: Sadly this was what I was forced to do as well